# How do I capture the command line output of an already running application?

Tags: windows, command-line, buffer

I have a process which is started by another process, so I cannot see the command line output of the launched process, how can I check the console output anyway? Can I "attach" the command line to a process? if yes, how?

Edit:
I mean this:

[image]

Comment: Your question is fully unclear. What are all those numbers supposed to mean? Add some example of your program that calls a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will be useful for you.

[StraceNT - A System Call Tracer for Windows](http://www.intellectualheaven.com/?BH=projects&H=strace.htm)

> StraceNT is a System Call Tracer for Windows. It provides similar functionality as of strace on Linux. It can trace all the calls made by a process to the imported functions from a DLL. StraceNT can be very useful in debugging and analyzing the internal working of a program.

I am a Linux person and use `strace` for this sort of things. You will get more than just your program output because if it works like `strace` it would be quite verbose, however, you may need to filter the output to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Link is dead. This appears to be a similar, if not the same, project:
https://github.com/ipankajg/stracent